# How to select just fist data in datagridview

Tags: c#

I have a problem i tried to get just first data in datagridview.I tried with this code:

```
String x = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

But i get this error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index

Comment: Please include the entire event handler code snippet.

Comment: Are you selecting any of your grid row? did you set Selection Mode: FullRowSelect?

Comment: `KorisniciBazaPodataka bpk = new KorisniciBazaPodataka();
 String x = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
  ModelKorisici pojediniKorisnik = bpk.DajPojedinogKorisnika(x);frmUrediKorisnika frmUrediKor = new frmUrediKorisnika(pojediniKorisnik);
            frmUrediKor.Show();
`

Comment: A datagridview will have -1 row count until the the columns are added.  Since you are getting a negative index it means there are no columns added.

Comment: butt i filled the datagiedview with datas

Comment: so if you want to get data from your datagridview then you must write getting data code after felling it. so if you can't fell you can't get.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data of 1st row and 1st cell you may write like that:

```
 string x = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value;
```

If you want the data of 1st row and 1st column you may write any of it:

```
string x = dataGridView1["ColumnName", rowNo].Value.ToString();
string x = dataGridView1[colunmNo, rowNo].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan